# How can I implement ECDsa in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to implement ECDsa in Windows Phone. So far, all I see available is a third-party library like Bouncy Castle. .NET 4.5 supposedly has ECDsa (and ECDHE) available, but the libraries are currently unavailable in my current environment (likely not included in the .NET Subset).

I would like to use it to sign messages between an Windows Phone app and a WinRT app, and WinRT has access to it through the AsymmetricAlgorithmProvider.

Does anyone have any advice?